# October CMS Static Pages plugin - hide / show pages in the backend based on user roles?

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, static-pages

How can I hide some static pages based on the user's role?

I defined the role of users with the name "blabla".
Now I want to hide all the pages from these users, except for the page "blabla" in the "Static Pages" backend.
How can i do this?

sorry for my English))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes of course you can do it but we need to write some code here.

we can utilize **cms.object.listInTheme** event

In your plugin within boot method you can add this event listener and filter static pages.

```
\Event::listen('cms.object.listInTheme', function ($cmsObject, $objectList) {

    // lets check if we are really running in static pages
    // you can also add more checks here based on controllers etc ..
    if ($cmsObject instanceof \RainLab\Pages\Classes\Page) {

        $user = \BackendAuth::getUser();
        // role code and role name are different things
        // we should use role code as it act as constant
        $hasRoleFromWhichIneedTohidePages = $user->role->code === 'blabla' ? true : false;

        // if user has that role then we start filtering
        if($hasRoleFromWhichIneedTohidePages) {
            foreach ($objectList as $index => $page) {

                // we can use different matching you can use one of them
                // to identify your page which you want to hide. 
                // forgot method will hide that page

                // match against filename 
                if ($page->fileName == 'hidethispage.htm') {
                    $objectList->forget($index);
                }

                // OR match against title
                if ($page->title == 'hidethispage') {
                    $objectList->forget($index);
                }

                // OR match against url
                if ($page->url == '/hidethispage') {
                    $objectList->forget($index);
                }
             }
         }
    }
});
```

currently this code will check **page-url / title / file-name** and restrict user statically from showing page in list but you can put your own logic here and make things dynamic.

if you didn't get it or want dynamic solution then please comment , I will explain in more detail.

Comment: Thanks. How can I find the code of the current user role and check the permissions? If the permission with the name "Manager" is "checked", then start filtering ... Need make things dynamic. This should work for all roles where the "Manager" permission checkbox is selected. I will be very grateful for the detailed answer:)

Comment: I can develop small plugin for that as its bad idea to attach some pages to show based on permission. instead i think to make plugin which can take usergroups and assign pages to it, then we can assign that user group to user then only assigned pages will be accessible.

Comment: any how to show sub-page as well we can not show page whose parent is remove from list instead we can  show message when user click on restricted page -> "you don't have access to this page" (downfall of this will : it will show "all pages" and when user click on page to edit at that time user can identify i don't have access to it)

Comment: Yes, maybe using groups.

My project:

Role & Permissions or user groups:
- The company has many branches in different cities.
- Managers should have access to editing only their branch.
- Directors should have access to editing of all branches and create new branches.

What exactly will they edit:
- Publish unique advertising messages for each of the branches.
Each advertisement must have its own page, in order to read more.
- Edit the photo album of each branch page.
- Edit some texts on the branch page.

Sub-pages for branch pages are also needed.

Comment: I don`t know how to do it in October CMS.
I tried to do this on Wordpress))
It turned out, everything works, but not perfect.
I would like to do this in October.

Comment: How do you think, how can this be realized?
Which way should I move?

Comment: ok, i can understand your issue , just i need one more info how branch is related to the Managers or Directors (in general users).  as for now i guess company , branch and user these are entities, company has many branches. one branches can have single manager(user). so i guess company has exactly one director (user) he can add branch and assign it a manager user i guess if i am not wrong.

Comment: i guess its doable, we don't need extra roles etc. we need usergroups manger and director only, then i guess real logic we need to apply is with in theme, as all static pages will be stored in theme, i consider in theme we create folder based on branch name , then manager with that branch can access that folder files (pages) and its sub pages, then manger can access same multiple branch name folders (branches which his company has) and we need to revoke CMS access from both users. if its ok then i can go further

Comment: (as october is flat file system) so basically if i am manager i can create pages within my branch only (within branch folder)  and i can add sub-folders as sub-pages, if i am director i can see all branches (all branch name folders which company has) and edit them or add them etc .. is that ok ? i can develop small plugin if its fine to you. (users can be identified from user-group) and branches associated to them will be fetched from database. now based on that we show them accessible (branch folders files inside it as page)

Comment: Please, see this picture))
I hope it will be more understandable
https://yadi.sk/i/Nv7Ax-nU3QQFyx

Comment: Yes, you think rightly.:)
Maybe go to chat or telegram or facebook?)) 
What not to write here a huge amount of text.

Comment: Can this problem be solved with the help of posts (Branch page) and sub-posts (advertising) + sub pages (to any information of Branch) in the plug-in?
Managers need create advertising sub-posts.
We can create a user-friendly interface in plug-in.
After all, managers do not understand anything in programming.

Comment: yes why not .. if you don't need that 'cms page' feature for your advertise(add), then you can define what parameters you need for your advertise (basically may be its an feature image, some text etc.. ) so we provide interface to post advertise. and in front it will be shown just like page no big deal there (if your requirement for advertisement page is basic then its perfect solution) my skype id : hardik_satasiya  you can contact me there.